# Failed to build stand-alone application on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10) with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, cx-freeze

I tried to build an application with cx_Freeze 4.3.1 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 but it didn't worked. I use python version 2.7 and use Tkinter as my GUI for development. If I use `python setup.py bdist_mac`on the terminal, the build process fail with the following error message:

> [Errno2]/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/versions/8.5/TCL no such file or directory

The newest version (8.5) of Tcl/Tk is already installed.

My setup file looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {
"includes": [],
"packages": [],
'excludes' : ['collections.abc', 'urllib.sys'],
"include_files": []}

setup(
    name = "application",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "",
    author = "",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("applicaton.py")]
)
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get it working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you do a few things here (*hopefully solving two issues I can identify*):

- Using Mac OS X's system Python (*not recommended*)
- Using old and unmaintained [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

First let's fix your Python installation! The recommended approach is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew doctor
brew update
brew install python
```

Now you should have a good installation of Python in `/usr/local` that's separate from your Mac OS X system Python so you can keep things clean and separate. You should also have followed any recommended instructions from the above installation. Typically this involves modifying your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

**Note:** Normally you should modify your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.profile` depending on how you have your Terminal configured.

You should now also have `pip` form `/usr/local/bin/pip` available as well.

Now on to a better replacement for [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) -- The recommended and more maintained approach these days is to use [pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/):

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller -F /path/to/my/script.py
```

For more complex requirements and builds please follow pyinstaller's documentation on [Using sepc files](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-spec-files)

Good luck!

**Note:** This *should* also fix your TCL/TK problem as well hopefully!

Comment: I tried to use your recommended fix of the python installation, but if I use `brew install python` there is an error message which said `You must 'brew link gdbm' before python can be installed`. So, If I tried this one, there is another message that said `Could not symlink share/info/gdbm.info usr/local/share/info is not writable`. However, I just continued with your suggestions and the build process worked with pyInstaller! Thanks for that. But the file that is produced is a  _Unit Executable File_, so I cannot open the application. Can you tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Yeah it's likely you'll have to cleanup your ``/usr/local`` and ensure your local user has write permissions to it. Generally I find nuking the contents of ``/usr/local`` and making sure I have write access to it works just fine :) Nothing usually writes to ``/usr/local`` -- except Homebrew of course :)