# error: [Errno 2] Python3

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert a py file to a .exe using cx_Freeze. I used Python 3.6 to made the program and I'm using a Mac.

I've watched many tutorials on YouTube and I understand I have to create a file named setup.py with the following code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name='program',
      version='0.1',
      description = 'program for mun',
      executables = [Executable('main.py')]
      )
```

And then when in Terminal I must enter:

```
python3 setup.py build
```

After some seconds it shows the following error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Tcl'
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: Does your python program need `Tcl`? you might try to add another definition in your `setup()` function (similar to how you have`name=`, `version=`), make a new entry `options = {
        "build_exe" : {
            "excludes": ['tcl', 'ttk', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'], 
        }
    },` as in this answer [How do I use cx_Freeze on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105302/1248974)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use cx\_Freeze on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104990/how-do-i-use-cx-freeze-on-mac)

Comment: Hi, I have tried that and it shows the same error.

Comment: you created a `setup.py` but ran `setup` on `main.py`? what if you try `python3 setup.py bdist_mac`, or `python3.6 setup.py bdist_mac`

Comment: Also, maybe take a look at this answer [Failed to build stand-alone application on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10) with cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386804/1248974)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to build stand-alone application on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10) with cx\_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386732/failed-to-build-stand-alone-application-on-mac-os-x-yosemite-10-10-with-cx-fre)

Comment: @downshift Sorry that was a typo, I ran it like you said and the error is still there.

Comment: @downshift The link you attached ('Failed to...') uses pyinstaller and as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong, it (pyinstaller) doesn't support python 3.6 yet.

Comment: @Arturo.Mart yes you are right, `pyinstaller` doesn't support py3.6